# react native: How to pass an action to a screen react navigation, (without Redux)?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I almost finished my first react-native app (i'm a beginner), but i've got a big problem, i can't pass an action between my 2 screens 'Home.js' and 'Favoris.js', i want when i click on the save button, my 'favoris' screen refresh the content, but i didn't find. (No redux please)

I write in  files: index.android.js and in the components folder with 'Home.js' and 'Favoris.js'

i put all my code in github:
https://github.com/igaman/inspiness

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you please be more clear? Where's your 'save button'? What do you expect by pressing it? What actually happens? Thx

Comment: when i click it save the data in asyncstorage, and it's work well. But i want to automatically refresh the 'favori.js' screen, actually i have a button to refresh the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a method in index.android.js and pass it to home.js as prop. Pass this method further to quoteDetail.js as prop. Call this method from quoteDetail.js. When this method is called, it is executed inside index.android.js. From inside the method's body in index.android.js, you can call a navigator to favoris screen.